# iBeacons: bearing to beacon?

Tags: ibeacon

Partly a coding problem, partly math problem.

Q1. I have an iOS device with compass active. If it knows I'm moving through the field of an iBeacon - or the Beacon is moving through my detection range - would it be possible for a phone to work out (roughly) the relative direction/bearing of that beacon with a series of readings by comparing signal strengths? Has anyone had a try at this?

Q2. Would it be possible to change the Major and Minor values of a beacon regularly (eg: every second) to pass small pieces of info - such as a second user's Bearing and Course?

Comment: Even if the distance metric were perfect (which is isn't), it doesn't really seem like the orientation heading of the phone would be of much use to know in order to deduce beacon location, rather you would want to know the phone's local *position* corresponding to each signal strength reading.  Orientation would really only help if you were trying to model BLE antenna directionality, but that may be hard without including the user's hand and body.

Answer (score 3):

Q1. It MIGHT be possible but you would need a controlled environment. Either the beacon or the phone needs to be fixed. You also need to be in an area with no obstructions or sources of radio interference.

Then you'd need to use the signal strength (which is sloppy and varies by a fair amount) as one input, and the device's heading info (which is also grossly inaccurate) and do some petty gnarly math on it.

Assuming you could work out the math, the slop in the input readings might make the results too iffy to be useful. (For example, how would you distinguish moving directly towards the beacon from moving 30 degrees to one side or the other? The signal strength would still increase, just not as quickly.

And your algorithm would have to deal with edge cases like moving along a circle around the beacon. In that case the signal strength should not change.

My gut is that even with clever algorithms that input data is just too unreliable to make much sense out of it, beyond "getting warmer" and "getting colder."

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you'd have to track your device's movement within the field, including distance covered and direction, then with multiple readings of signal strength you could theoretically calculate relative direction to the beacon to some degree of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

As to your second question about changing the minor version number, I have not seen any beacon APIs that allow that, either from the beacon manufacturers or from Apple's implementation.

However, a typical beacon is an ARM or other low power processor with a BLE transceiver, running a program. In theory it should be possible to create your own iBeacon transmitter that changed one of the parameters in order to transmit changing information. You'd have to set up the iOS device with the beacon region only specifying the UUID or UUID and major ID (depending on whether you wanted to change just the minor or change both the major and minor ID in order to transmit changing information.)

Note, too, that iBeacons are a special case of BLE, and the BLE standard does support the sending of arbitrary, changing data. You might be better off implementing your own BLE scheme either instead of or in addition to iBeacons.